# Request for member view in something not in a structure or union?

Tags: iphone

```
UIButton *playButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
playButton.frame = CGRectMake(110.0, 360.0, 100.0, 30.0);
[playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"];
UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"];
UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
**//[self.view addSubview:playButton];**
```

Comment: it is showing error in commented line

Comment: Where did you place that code? What type has current class?

Comment: Actually i want to create a button with out using IB

Comment: There's a mismatch of brackets in the first line.

Comment: Please post the precise error message including the the line number. Then tell us which line in your code the error message referes to. And we'll probably also need the header file.

Comment: correct this line:- UIButton *playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

Comment: and this line also //**[self.view addSubview:playButton];**

Comment: hey at the end i tried like this [self addSubView:playButton];but it is showing some warning like delegate may not respond to addSubview

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing this in a class which is a subclass of UIView

you should try

```
[self addSubview:playButton];
```

Comment: Hey i tried this but it is showing some warning like delegate may not respond to addSubview

Comment: In which class are you writing this code. What is the type of the class?

Comment: Im doing this in implementation class

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UntitledAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIWindow *window;@end

Comment: you are doing it in app delegate. then try `[self.window addSubview:button];`

Comment: use a view controller and add its view to the window and use your previous code in that view controller. That is the approach

Comment: I tried by doing [self.window addSubView:button] ... it succeeded but it is not displaying anything just a black screen

Comment: how do you show the window i mean how do you populate the window?

Comment: I wrote The whole code in this applicationDidFinishLaunching only

Comment: [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; is missing in your other question

Comment: pls dont keep on asking questions. You can update the existing ones

Comment: i have that in my code ... even though it is showing the same blank screen

Comment: It was not there in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788825/my-program-is-succeeding-but-it-is-showing-a-black-screen

Answer (score 0):

First create the view

```
UIView *myview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];   
[self.view addSubview:myview];
```

Then add this button to this view like this.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[myview addSubview:button];
```

Try this.. if it is not working communicate with me...

Comment: If `[self.view addSubview:button];` displays the error how can `[self.view addSubview:myview];` not display it?