# My program is succeeding but it is showing a black screen

Tags: iphone

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UntitledAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIWindow *window;
@end


#import "UntitledAppDelegate.h"

@implementation UntitledAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    UIButton *playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(110.0, 360.0, 100.0, 30.0);
    [playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
    playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.gif"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Crown.png"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self .window addSubview:playButton];
return YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

create IBOutlet of the window like this --> IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
then open MainWindow.xib and connect this window iboutlet to the UntitledAppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Try this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    UIButton *playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(110.0, 360.0, 100.0, 30.0);
    [playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
    playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.gif"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Crown.png"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self .window addSubview:playButton];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: I already had that line ... eventhough it is showing the black screen

Comment: Then check if the window outlet is made and connected properly. From your code window is not an IBOutlet

Answer (score 0):

Add in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: the line:

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFram: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```